# How to access parent view and controller from ember eventManager

Tags: ember.js

### The ember way:

According to ember's [documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#toc_event-managers) about views' eventManagers, they must be `created` in the parent classes definition like so:

```
AView = Ember.View.extend({
  eventManager: Ember.Object.create({
```

which encapsulates and isolates them from their parent view `(AView)`.

The only way of accessing the context of events is through the `view` parameter that gets passed in along with each `event`

```
dragEnter: function(event, view) {
```

### My situation:

I'm doing a lot of work with the various drag events inside a large view with many subviews, inputs, checkboxes, etc. 
Following this form, my code is beginning to go to great lengths to determine which sub-view each event originated from, and then taking different paths to access the common parent controller:

```
drop: function(event, view) {
  var myController;
  if(view.$().hasClass('is-selected') || 
      view.$().hasClass('list-map-container')) {
    myController = view.get('controller.controllers.myController');
  } else if(view.$().hasClass('ember-text-field')) { 
    myController = view.get('parentView.parentView.controller');
  } else {
    myController = view.get('controller');
  }
  // do work with myController
}
```

### My hack:

In order to simplify I used the `didInsertElement` hook in the parent view to assign the desired controller as a property on the eventManager:

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.set('eventManager.controller', this.get('controller'));
  },
  eventManager: Ember.Object.create({
    controller: null,
    // ...
```

This works to significantly simplify my event handlers:

```
drop: function(event, view) {
  var myController = this.get('controller');
  // do work with myController
```

### My question:

My intuition tells me this hack-around isn't the best solution.

Perhaps I shouldn't be doing all the work in the eventManager? Rather move all this work to a controller and just forward the events from the view?

But if the eventManager is an acceptable workspace, then what is the best way to access the parent view's controller?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a late answer but this SO question appears as a result of google. Here is how I did this when searching through emberjs examples.

To access the view within the `eventManager`, you have to specify two argument in the event function handler :

```
eventManager: Ember.Object.create({
  keyUp: function(event, view){
    view = view.get('parentView'); // The view parameter might not be the current view but the emberjs internal input view.
    view.get('controller'); // <-- controller
  }
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like all the controller logic is encapsulated to a text-field--if so, I think a component might better suited for this use case.  It's essentially a controller and view as one, and the eventManager's callbacks' view parameter gives you control over the component/controller itself.

If you need access to the component's parent controller, you might want to bind to events on the component from the parent controller, because the component really shouldn't know about anything outside its scope.